# For what is the JsonObjectAttribute.Id?

Tags: c#, json.net

JSON.NET [`JsonObjectAttribute`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonObjectAttribute.htm) has a property [`Id`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonContainerAttribute_Id.htm). It's inherited from the [`JsonContainerAttribute`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonContainerAttribute.htm). I cannot find, for what is the `Id` property is used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's used by [Json.NET Schema](https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema) to override the default [`"$id"`](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/structuring.html#id) property value when generating a schema for a type.

E.g. if I have the following type:

```
[JsonObject(Id = "http://foo.bar/schemas/rootobject.json")]
public class RootObject { }
```

And auto-generate a schema using [`JSchemaGenerator`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Schema_Generation_JSchemaGenerator.htm) as follows:

```
var schema = new JSchemaGenerator().Generate(typeof(RootObject)).ToString();
```

The result is (demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WcVmWO)):

```
{
  "$id": "http://foo.bar/schemas/rootobject.json",
  "type": "object"
}
```

When not overridden, the value of `"$id"` is controlled by the [`SchemaIdGenerationHandling`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Schema_Generation_JSchemaGenerator_SchemaIdGenerationHandling.htm) enumeration.

It was also used by the [obsolete `JsonSchemaGenerator`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Schema_JsonSchemaGenerator.htm) according to [JamesNK](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/2023#issuecomment-478212457):

> It was used by JsonSchemaGenerator but that is deprecated.