# JsonObject Attribute

Tags: json.net

So i have class with JsonObject Attribute(from Newtonsoft.json) here i place some value for Description Title and Id. But when i serialize it and looking for string that i made, i dont see any description or id there

```
[JsonObject(Description = "Something", Title = "Something", Id = "Something")]
    class Client : Utility.ObserableObject
    {
        string name;
        string description;
        string phone;
        Activity activity;
        string image_path;
       

        public Client()
        {
            ImagePath = "Resources\\DefaultImages\\default_user.png";
            Activity = Activity.Active;
        }

        public string Name { get => name; set => Set(ref name, value); }
        public string Description { get => description; set => Set(ref description, value); }
        public string Phone { get => phone; set => Set(ref phone, value); }
        public Activity Activity { get => activity; set => Set(ref activity, value); }
        public string ImagePath { get => image_path; set => Set(ref image_path, value); }
    }



////////////////writing data///////////
  Client client = new Client();
  client.Name = "MyName";
  client.Description = "MyDesc";
  client.Phone = "MyPhone";
  client.ImagePath = "MyImage";

 string str = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(client, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
 Console.WriteLine(str);


/////////////output of serialization//////////
// where are thise (Description = "Something", Title = "Something", Id = "Something")?
{
  "Name": "MyName",
  "Description": "MyDesc",
  "Phone": "MyPhone",
  "Activity": 0,
  "ImagePath": "MyImage"
}
```

Comment: Related: [For what is the JsonObjectAttribute.Id?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35790617/3744182).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JsonObjectAttribute's properties such as Id,Title and Description, is used to support Json schema definition. To view how it imapacts the Schema, please refer the following example,

```
[JsonObject(Description = "Something", Title = "Something", Id = "Something")]
 public class Foo
 {
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public string Address{get;set;}
 }

 public class Bar
 {
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public string Address{get;set;}
 }
```

In the above example, we have two classes Foo and Bar. One of the them, Foo, has been decorated with the JsonObjectAttribute to define the Description, Title and Id. Now, when generating the schema for both,

```
var schemaGenerator = new Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.Generation.JSchemaGenerator();
var fooSchema = schemaGenerator.Generate(typeof(Foo)).ToString();
var barSchema = schemaGenerator.Generate(typeof(Bar)).ToString();
```

Generated Schema for Foo and Bar as follows

**Foo**

```
{
  "$id": "Something",
  "title": "Something",
  "description": "Something",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "Name": {
      "type": [
        "string",
        "null"
      ]
    },
    "Address": {
      "type": [
        "string",
        "null"
      ]
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "Name",
    "Address"
  ]
}
```

**Bar**

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "Name": {
      "type": [
        "string",
        "null"
      ]
    },
    "Address": {
      "type": [
        "string",
        "null"
      ]
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "Name",
    "Address"
  ]
}
```

You can now observe how the attribute has impacted the schema definition. The Id (which translates to $id) is [used to uniquely identify a schema](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/basics.html#id4). Similarly, the [Title and Description](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/generic.html#id2) are used to provide a short/long description for the Schema.

[Demo Code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ri7Arx)

Comment: *JsonObjectAttribute is used to support Json schema definition.* -- while these three properties are used only for schema definition, most other properties of `JsonObjectAttribute` affect serialization as well.

Comment: grateful for the help

Comment: @EmilAbbas Glad to help you. If it was helpful and answered your query, kindly mark it as answer/helpful so that it could be useful for others who have the similar query